# How can I get the position of a fixture in Farseer Physics 3.5?

Tags: c#, xna, farseer-physics-engine

I created a body(rectangle). After that, I attached a circle shape to the body.

I need the position(world coodinates) of the circle shape because I want to draw a circle sprite(Texture2D) on that position.

How can I get the world coodinates of the fixture?

```
Body Rectangle;
Rectangle = BodyFactory.CreateRectangle(world, 1.50f, 0.50f, 1.0f);
Rectangle.BodyType = BodyType.Static;
Rectangle.Position = new Vector2(4.8f, 6.4f);
Rectangle.Rotation = (float)(60 * Math.PI / 180);

CircleShape = new FarseerPhysics.Collision.Shapes.CircleShape(0.5f, 1.0f);
CircleShape.Position = new Vector2(1.0f, 0.0f);
Fixture fixture = Rectangle.CreateFixture(CircleShape, 1.0f);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to get the position of the fixture's body.

```
Vector2 position = fixture.Body.Position;
```